# List item first row not aligning properly

Tags: css

I have this unordered list

http://neaen.com/frying/neaen-masterfry-continuous-fryer.html

Whichever combination I tried using FireBug, I can't get the first row to align properly. I am sure this is an easy fix, but I am missing it somehow.

Comment: why are you repetitively giving anchor tag inside anchor tag

Comment: Wait why are you using <pre> for your elements?

Comment: This is WordPress plugin, I was asked to modify CSS, not the plugin since the next update would overwrite the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are caused by line breaks in the list items. Do one of two things. Either remove all spaces between each `</li><li>` or remove the closing `</li>` altogether. This is valid.

Comment: This is correct, this is the answer I've needed - I will need to modify a plugin (this is WordPress), I see there is an extra row added after every li element.

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of the unordered list code entirely and use divs to make this work.  Then you could put only a single link for each of the boxes and have the entire box be the link for each one.

You will have more options for styling and positioning your content that way.

Here is a source you can look at for that: http://css-tricks.com/creating-clickable-divs/

Apologies if this doesn't answer the specific question.

Comment: This is WordPress plugin, I was asked to modify CSS, not the plugin since the next update would overwrite the changes.